# Can http POST variables be case sensitive?

Tags: asp.net, http-post

I have a web service proxy that calls another web service with a user name and password to authenticate a user to the site the proxy is in. All of the "normal" forms authentication is handled by the proxy but it then needs to talk to a database behind the remote web service to determine if a user is actually valid. I need to ensure that the password is passed to the remote service in a case sensitive manner for security/strong password reasons.

At present it's issuing an http GET over SSL but as the GET uses an MVC url with the details in it's not case sensitive.

If I change this to POST will I get case sensitivity?

Comment: I don't think this has anything to do with the HTTP protocol; it has to do with how your web server handles the request. In addition, shouldn't the request be handled with some sort of authentication handshake token, rather than sending the password in the clear?

Comment: Ok, I'll look into the web serve side of things & we may want to implement a handshake instead but in this case the server the proxy is on is public facing but the "remote" server is actually not publicly accessible by client code, just the proxy server ( or so I'm told by our sys admin) you have made me concerned about that too now, so I'll check that too.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

HTTP parameters are case sensitive.

I experienced this firsthand as late as today. I had an old HTML form I used for testing while developing a webapp, and I've changed the case of one character of one of the parameters since the creation of the form. When I today tried to use it again my webapp didn't recognize the old variable name. If the HTTP protocol had defined parameter names as case insensitive this should still have worked.

Judging by your formulations, it seems more likely the problem is that your programs are not case sensitive.

Comment: Good news! I'll retest in the morning, I've probably make a mistake somewhere due to the late hour :)